# .Angular index.html only working after ng build

Tags: angular, router, ng-build

My angular router works very well on localhost:4200 but not working after ng-build. Only showing index.html after ng-build.

Comment: Please Stop Writing With Upper Case Letters.

Answer (score 0):

you have to post more than this - you set the output parameters of build to probably default dist folder or public folder, and inside that folder is where your build is located at.

https://angular.io/cli/build